# SQLITE and Swift 3 Challenge

Tags: swift, sqlite

Trying to retrieve an array of data from SQLite, in Swift and am drawing the error:

```
API called with NULL prepared statement
misuse at line 83492 of [2b0954060f]
```

However, I am using the same code in a different classes with success.

I have create taken the label and want to see if the full array contains that details of that label.  if so, I will auto I will auto load other details.

I cannot see the error causing this issue.

here is what i have:

```
class NewSpeciesVC: UIViewController, ItemDataSelectedProtocol
{

    var genusDetail: GenusDetailModel = GenusDetailModel()
    var familyDetail: FamilyDetailModel = FamilyDetailModel()
    var orderDetail: OrderDetailModel = OrderDetailModel()


   let userDefault = UserDefaults.standard
   var userDatabase: UserDatabase = UserDatabase()
   var rlDatabase = RLDatabase()

    func loadMatchingGenusKeys () {

    let genusLabelTest = genusLabel.text
    if (genusLabelTest?.isEmpty == false)
    {
        let genus:String = genusLabel.text!

        let genusListItems = rlDatabase.getGenusNames()

        print("genus selected is \(genus)")
        print("genus list is \(genusListItems)")

        if genusListItems.contains(genus) {

   ...

        } else {
            return
        }

    } else {
        return
    }

}
}
```

results of above print:

genus selected is Acanthella

genus list is []

```
 class RLDatabase
 {

 func getGenusNames() -> Array<String>   { return self.getArrayOfStringsForQuery(query: SQL.SelectNameOfGenus)}

private func getArrayOfStringsForQuery(query: String) -> Array<String>
{
    var arrayOfStrings: Array<String> = [String]()

    if self.database == nil
    {
        return arrayOfStrings
    }

    var statement: OpaquePointer? = nil

    sqlite3_prepare_v2(self.database, query, -1, &statement, nil)
    while sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW
    {
        let item = String(cString: (sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)))

        //
        //  Add the string to our array of strings.
        //
        arrayOfStrings.append(item)
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement)

    //
    //  Return a list of all the strings we found.
    //
    return arrayOfStrings
}



struct SQL
{
static let SelectNameOfGenus            = "SELECT name FROM Genus"
}
```

Comment: You must check the return value of `sqlite3_prepare_v2`. If it is not `SQLITE_OK` you need to check the error using `sqlite3_errmsg`.

Comment: How to capture the error msg with "while"?  I know how with the "if".

Comment: The problem is before the `while` statement. Just do something like `guard sqlite3_prepare_v2(...) == SQLITE_OK else { ... }`. And if it does fail, you should look at `sqlite3_errmsg` to figure out why precisely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check below code. I have not tested it in Xcode, but will help you to give heads up to capture error handling.

```
if sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, "SELECT name FROM Genus", -1, &statement, nil) != SQLITE_OK {
    let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(database)!)
    print("preparing  error: \(errmsg)")
}
do {
    while sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW {
        let item = String(cString: (sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)))
    }
} 
catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}

if sqlite3_finalize(statement) != SQLITE_OK {
    let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(database)!)
    print("finalizing error: \(errmsg)")
}
```

Comment: 1. If `sqlite3_prepare_v2` failed, you should not proceed. No point in calling `sqlite3_step` nor `sqlite3_finalize` in that case. 2. The `do`-`catch` pattern makes no sense, because you're not calling anything that throws errors.